# Implementing background blur with screen recording in JavaScript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tensorflow, bodypix

I'm trying to implement a background blur effect with screen recording.

currently, we are using the "api.video" library in our MVC project, but we can't find any features regarding this
 
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about trying to Blur the background of a video that's captured via a webcam?  Because the apivideo library only handles capture/streaming. Background blurring, ala Zoom or Meet, happens through the application of Machine Learning Models that take the video, identify a person, and then apply filters to the rest of frame (to put it simply).  You would want to look into the use of something like TensorFlow.js to achieve that result.

Comment: I want to add background blur with this library there are some library available but are not with this library together.